# Why I can not change the value of global variable in WatchKit - swift?

Tags: swift, global-variables, watchkit

I'm making a simple WatchKit application. I have a golbal int variable with value is 0 in first InterfaceController.

Here is my first interface:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import UIKit

var index:Int = 0

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    .....
}
```

in the secondView Interface i want to change the value of this global variable:

```
import UIKit
import WatchKit

class secondInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {


    override init(context: AnyObject?) {
        // Initialize variables here.
        super.init(context: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
        NSLog("%@ init", self)

        println("index: \(index)")

        index = 2


    }


}
```

But i received an error: "Cannot assign to the result of this expression" for variable index. I don't know why and i want to know how to do that. I can change the value of global variable for application for IOS. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. When you want to use a global variable inside interfaces, you have to set all that interfaces to same "Target Membership"

Comment: This solution has nothing to do with Global variables... If your two interface controllers are in separate targets, you can't use any aspects of the class in the target it isn't installed in. This really should not be marked as a solution to the question you originally posed.

Comment: For example, I have a global variable in my fist interface controller, This interface controller has 2 target member ship for "IOS app" and "watchkit app". If my second interface controller has only one target "watchkit app" and I can not use this global variable. But if i add more target "IOS app" to my second controller, i can use the that global value. That 's what i mean in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced your code to test the problem, intending to test potential solutions. Instead, I confirmed that this issue was not reproducible.

To be able to run the code, I had to change it to `override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?)`. From the release notes of both beta3 and the beta4 released today:

> The WKInterfaceController method initWithContext: has been deprecated. Please use awakeWithContext: instead. The designated initializer for WKInterfaceController is now init.

Given your code uses `init(context: AnyObject?)` and you are not receiving this error message:

> Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

...it indicates that you are using a version of Xcode 6.2 earlier than beta 3. Therefore, it is possible there was a bug in an earlier beta that was causing your issue. Updating to today's beta4 release and re-testing this issue would be highly advisable.

---

On an associated note, there are many programmers who would argue that the use of global variables is highly undesirable, and that the use of another approach, even a singleton, is preferable. I just draw this to your attention to look into if you don't already have formed opinions on this debate.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, so I want to know how can we send a data from one Interface to another interface and send back to another Interface? I know i can send a data with context option but I don't know how to send back a data to previous Interface. How can I do that?

Comment: Great question for a specific question, which we can then answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that if this answer has assisted you solve your question, you should click on the tick next to the answer to mark it as accepted. Even when you don't have enough reputation to upvote, you can always accept an answer to your own question. :)